# Filter a list by omitting values by indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I did not find an easy way to filter a list **excluding** values by their indexes. For example, I have:

```
varList = ['r', 2, ('c'), ['e'], 'etc.', { 'su': 'lt'}]
indexList = [1, 2, 4]
```

and I need to have:

```
expected = ['r', ['e'], {'su': 'lt'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be using list comprehension:

```py
    [value for index,value in enumerate(varList) if index not in indexList]
```

Comment: This is exactly the same that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65108666/6045800) is suggesting...

Comment: Yeah, because that's the most basic and easiest way to accomplish that task.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way would be:

```
[x for i, x in enumerate(varList) if i not in indexList]
```

which is `O(m * n)` for `m = len(varList)` and `n = len(indexList)`. While that is okay for short exclusion lists, for some significant speedup with longer lists you may want to say instead:

```
indexset = set(indexList)
[x for i, x in enumerate(varList) if i not in indexset]
```

Which is `O(m)` only (plus `O(n)` to make the set).

Comment: I am relatively new in Python and appreciate your thoughtful comments

Comment: you're welcome; you may consider accepting the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is as the following with the options to *omit* and to *extract*:

```
def getFilteredListByIndexes(
  varList: list, indexList: list, mode: str = 'omit') -> list:
  """ @Function to filter varlist by indexList
    @Args:
      varList: list or tuple of any type
      indexList: list of tuple of integers
      mode: str, that could be 'omit' or 'extract'
  """
  resTuple = ()
  res = []
  if mode == 'omit':
    resTuple = list(filter(lambda x: not x[0] in indexList, enumerate(varList)))
  elif mode == 'extract':
    resTuple = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in indexList, enumerate(varList)))
  else:
    resTuple = varList.emumerate()
  res = list(map(lambda x: x[1], resTuple))

  return res
```

Usage:

```
varList = ['r', 2, ('c'), ['e'], 'etc.', { 'su': 'lt'}]
indexList = [1, 2, 4]
expected = ['r', ['e'], {'su': 'lt'}]

res = getFilteredListByIndexes(varList, indexList, 'omit')

print(res)  # ['r', ['e'], {'su': 'lt'}]
```

Comment: there are a few gotchas about this: 1. do not use mutable default values for arguments default value ([see here why](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments)). 2. checking membership in a list is O(n) for list of length n; very slow. 3. map/filter/lambda etc. is okay (and I spent years of my life having fun transforming every challenge I would meet into MapReduce, for scale reasons) but I [agree with Guido](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196) that they make things much less readable than list enumeration and direct test.

Answer (score 0):

An in-place solution:

```py
for i in indexList[::-1]:
    del varList[i]
```

<sup>Assuming the list of indexes is ascending.</sup>

It is necessary to loop from the end to keep the indexes true (if we start by deleting index `1`, the element in index 2 will move to index 1 and then we will delete the wrong element). For a more general solution use `sorted(indexList, reverse=True)`.